# KnockoutJS: Setting optionValue breaks "with" binding

Tags: knockout.js

I was wondering if anyone had any insight as to why this code is breaking. When I remove the function which returns the productID, the tbody data-bind `with: chosenProduct` works correctly, but leaving the function in causes data-bind `"value: marketName"` to throw an error which states **"Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return marketName }" Message: marketName is not defined ".** This makes me think that for some reason `chosenProduct` is not being set as the value when the selection is made.

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><label>Product Name</label></td><td><select id="productSelect" data-bind="options: products, optionsCaption: 'Choose Product',optionsValue: function(i){ return i.productID }, optionsText:'productName', value: chosenProduct, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"></select></td></tr>
    <tbody data-bind="with: chosenProduct">
        <tr><td><label>Market</label></td><td><input type="text" readonly data-bind="value: marketName"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>Client</label></td><td><input type="text" readonly data-bind="value: clientName"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Javascript:

```
this.products = /* ajax call returns array of product objects*/;
chosenProduct = ko.observable();
    resetProduct = function() { this.chosenProduct(null);};
```

A product object:

```
{productID: 1, marketName: "Test", clientName: "Client1"}
```

Comment: @haim770 chosenProduct is set by the "value: chosenProduct" data-binding. When a user chooses an item from the select box, the object with the chosen attributes becomes the "chosenProduct".

Comment: @haim770 To expand on my previous comment: By having the chosenProduct act as an observable, it allows for two way binding. It can be set by the user choosing a select option (as mentioned in my previous comment) or set by a function within Javascript.

Comment: see my answer.  knockout is best left to have the actual product object as the `chosenProduct`.  Using the `ChosenProductID` you can read the chosen ID, and if you look at the [writable computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) documentation, you can adapt it so when written with an ID, it will go and look in your list of products to set the correct one into `chosenProduct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep the `optionsValue` binding so that the `chosenProduct` is purely an ID that is read/writable so you can set it elsewhere in javascript, the alternative to my other answer is to create a [`computed observable`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) that just shows the current product.  This can then be used in your template binding:

```
this.chosenProductObject = ko.computed(function() {
    for (x = 0; x < this.products.length; x++)
        if (this.products[x].productID == this.chosenProduct())
            return this.products[x];
    return null;
}, this);
```

And a slight tweak to your html:

```
<tbody data-bind="with: chosenProductObject">
    <!-- as before -->
</tbody>
```

Comment: Be aware of what `this` refers to when dealing with these sort of constructs in knockout - there is information on the linked documentation page about how to set it.  It will vary depending how you're constructing your viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into the computed observables.

Answer (score 2):

It is your use of the [`optionsValue` setting](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).

By using this, you're telling knockout to set the actual value of the thing being selected to the product ID.  This is just a number, and doesn't have `marketName` and `clientName` properties.  The solution is to leave it removed.  Knockout works well with having things selected in this fashion - if you need the actual ID of the product selected elsewhere, I suggest creating an extra property on your viewmodel, eg:

```
this.ChosenProductID = ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.chosenProduct() != null)
        return this.chosenProduct().productID;

    return -1;
}, this);
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I originally added the optionValue in because I am trying to later call it with jQuery. Originally, the HTML for each option just has a blank value attribute. Do you think adding the value using the optionsAfterRender callback provided by Knockout would allow me to satisfy both requirements?

Comment: No - leave everything in knockout, and pretty much ignore anything you can see going on in the html.  See my other comment on the original post about computed observables for setting the chosen product with just an ID.  The examples in the documentation should get you going

Comment: I've had another thought - I'll post is as a separate answer as it comes at it from another approach - give me 2 mins...